# Why do I get different data over Local Server?

Tags: mdriven

I use now persistenceMapperWEBAPIClient1 as PersistentMapper with default Uri http://localhost:5000/api/A0_WebApi and default User: a/Password: 123456

While prototyping on Local Server I have saved some data for the same(default) user.

Now I start my application with persistenceMapperWEBAPIClient1 as PersistentMapper, but I get no data. So it seems I access quite different data from prototype and from my application. Is it a thing of prefix perhaps? But I use the same user in both cases

/Efim

Comment: This seems to be problem specific to your organization, this cannot be anserered. If not you should provide more information about persistenceMapperWEBAPIClient1.

Answer (score 0):

That is the answer of Hans:

The turnkey application can either go in prototype mode - then it saves to a xml file named as the model - controlled by App_Data/MDrivenServerOverride.xml

...or it can connect to an MDriverServer in one of two ways:

1. MDrivenServer is found relative to TurnkeyApp ./__MDrivenServer and user and pwd taken from App_Data/TurnkeySettings.xml
2. MDrivenServer is found from setting in App_Data/MDrivenServerOverride.xml  :
   http://localhost:5010/

https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/MDrivenServerOverride

/Hans